# Creating a new column in a Pandas DataFrame based on the previous quarter and the same ID in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

What I have is two very large datasets that I want to combine, but before I do, I want to make sure that the same columns with correct values are found in both. One of them is missing a column titled 'file', which should be based on values found in this column in the other dataframe and values found in a list. My code looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

quarters = ['2021q1', '2021q2', '2021q3', '2021q4', '2022q1',
            '2022q2', '2022q3', '2022q4', '2023q1', '2023q2']


df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['file', 'quarter', 'ident'])
df_test.file = ['file_1', 'file_1_v2', 'file_2_old', 'file_2_new', 'file_3']
df_test.quarter = ['2022q4', '2023q2', '2022q2', '2022q3', '2023q1']
df.ident = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

df_test2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns = ['quarter', 'ident'])
df_test2.quarter = ['2023q1', '2022q4', '2023q2']
df_test2.ident = [1, 2, 3]
```

In the second dataframe df_test2, I want to insert a column 'file' with values defined by the 'file' values in df_test for the quarter before the one shown in df_test2 for the same id-number 'ident'. So, for example, the 'ident' = 1 has quarter '2022q4' and '2023q2' in df_test and '2023q1' in df_test2. This means that I want the 'file' column to read 'file_1' in df_test2 since this was the file name for the previous quarter, and not 'file1_v2'. The end result should be a column in df_test2 that reads:

```
['file_1', 'file_2_new', 'file_3']
```

My idea is to look for the same id-number in both dataframes, compare the 'quarter' value in df_test2 with the previous quarter value in df_test and set the file name to be the same, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Didi you mean `file_2_new` instead of `file_2_old`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be file_2_new.

Comment: Makes more sense, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quarter periods to makes things easier (converting with [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)+[`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)), and then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) your dataframes:

```
# use quarter periods instead of strings
df_test['quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['quarter']).dt.to_period('Q')
df_test2['quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test2['quarter']).dt.to_period('Q')

# merge on the previous period
out = df_test2.merge(df_test.drop(columns='quarter'), how='left',
                     left_on=['ident', 'quarter'],
                     right_on=['ident', df_test['quarter'].add(1)])
```

Output:

```
  quarter  ident        file
0  2023Q1      1      file_1
1  2022Q4      2  file_2_new
2  2023Q2      3      file_3
```

Note that you can keep your strings and pass the periods as keys in the `merge` (keeping all columns here for the demo):

```
out = df_test2.merge(df_test, how='left',
                     suffixes=('_1', '_2'),
                     left_on=['ident', pd.to_datetime(df_test2['quarter'])
                                         .dt.to_period('Q')],
                     right_on=['ident', pd.to_datetime(df_test['quarter'])
                                          .dt.to_period('Q').add(1)])
```

Output:

```
  quarter_1   key_1  ident        file quarter_2
0    2023q1  2023Q1      1      file_1    2022q4
1    2022q4  2022Q4      2  file_2_new    2022q3
2    2023q2  2023Q2      3      file_3    2023q1
```